# VBA:program optimization

Tags: search, vba, timer

So this question is two parts.  The first is seeing whether there is a quick and simple code that I can incorporate into my current sub to check how fast the sub will take to run.  I just need precision down to seconds, and up to maybe a couple of minutes.

The 2nd is I am currently trying to optimize the run time of my sub.  It is a search function that allows a user to specify which variables to select to search for and displays the results on the following worksheet.  I've surfed the net and I've done the following general applications to speed up my program

1. disable screen updating at the beginning of my sub
2. avoid copy&paste to clipboard as much as possible

However, my program still takes ~5 to 10 seconds to run everytime the user runs a search.  I would like to decrease this time as much as possible.

I realize without looking at my code it is hard to give specific suggestions, but I am currently just looking for general suggestions.  If it is still slow after the general principles have been implemented I will post my code here.

My search program is a linear search program and stores the values into an array.  My search function can accomodate up to 4 search variables though and I store each search into an array and I consolidate the array at the end into a final results array.

Comment: How is your search implemented? linear? binary? Do you use caching/lookup tables or other optimizations?

Comment: Sometimes it can be faster to write data to an excel hidden sheet and use [Auto Filter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP005200178.aspx) with wildcard criteria to search.

Comment: I don't use lookup tables and I am not sure what you mean by caching Cularis.  I am a beginner at VBA so I'm still learning as I go.

Comment: Are you asking how to predict runtimes, or how to measure them? You say "how fast the sub *will* take to run"... In addition to disabling screenupdating you might also investigate setting calculation from automatic to manual (don't forget to set it back after you're done). You say you're only looking for general suggestions, but it's usually the case that the most effective optimizations may depend on exactly how your code is doing its task, so if you could add some details people may have additional suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use the GetTickCount API function. As long as you're not intending to measure time over weeks or months it should be accurate. Below is an example that shows different looping measures being timed. 1 tick = 1ms

```
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long 

Sub test() 
Dim nTime 

nTime = GetTickCount 
Set load_array = Range("a5:z65000") 
array_index = WorksheetFunction.Match("Test 15", WorksheetFunction.Index(load_array, 0, 1), 0) 

rngtimer = GetTickCount - nTime 


nTime = GetTickCount 
load_array = Range("a5:z65000").Value 
array_index = WorksheetFunction.Match("Test 15", WorksheetFunction.Index(load_array, 0, 1), 0) 

arraytimer = GetTickCount - nTime 


nTime = GetTickCount 
load_array = Range("a5:z65000").Value 
For a = LBound(load_array) To UBound(load_array) 
If load_array(a, 1) = "Test 15" Then 
array_index = a 
End If 
Next 

arraylooptimer = GetTickCount - nTime 

nTime = GetTickCount 

For a = 1 To 65000 
If Range("a5").Offset(a, 0) = "Test 15" Then 
array_index = a 
End If 
Next 

excelooptimer = GetTickCount - nTime 

MsgBox ("Range Search: " & rngtimer & vbCrLf & _ 
"Array Search: " & arraytimer & vbCrLf & _ 
"ArrayLoop Search: " & arraylooptimer & vbCrLf & _ 
"ExcelLoop Search: " & excelooptimer) 
End Sub
```